# Debugger for Thrift?

Tags: hbase, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm looking for a tool that can sniff, throttle and modify the messages over Thrift. Something very similar to Charles Web Proxy for Web development.  Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

How important is throughput? If it isn't very important (or at least, as a guidance), you might be interested in thrift-tools:

https://github.com/pinterest/thrift-tools/

It's written in Python, so it's mostly aimed at debugging traffic not rewriting real traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Thrift supports a lot of very different transports so there's hardly a common kind of debugger etc. for all of them. However, AFAIK for some languages (mostly C++ and/or Java, IIRC) there are a few protocols available that could serve as debugging aid. Besides that you have to use a tool matching the underlying physical transport you are using, e.g. Wireshark or the like.